# Problem with checkbox in Settings API

Tags: options, settings-api

I am trying to create a simple checkbox setting that toggles a section in a blog post on or off in a theme settings page.

Unfortunately it's not saving the checkbox setting. I check the box and when I refresh the page it is unchecked again. Either it is not saving the setting or the `checked` function isn't working. Am I missing something?

```
function theme_option_settings(){
    register_setting( 'prev-next-setting', 'prev-next' );
    add_settings_section( 'blog-section', 'Blog Section', 'change_blog_layout_section', 'theme-options' );
    add_settings_field( 'show-prev-next', 'Show Previous/Next Post Section', 'show_prev_next_field', 'theme-options', 'blog-section' );
}

function change_blog_layout_section(){
    echo "Change the blog layout section";
}

function show_prev_next_field(){
    echo get_option( 'prev-next' );
    echo "<input type='checkbox' id='prev-next' name='prev-next' value='1' ".checked(1, get_option('prev-next'), true)."/>";
}
```

Comment: The last argument of `checked()`, `$echo`, should be `false`, because you're already using it as part of an echo statement. If you just need to include it in a string, you need to return it.

Comment: I just changed that but it still won't save the checked setting.

Comment: Also, the value of the checkbox is `'1'`, a String, but you're using `1`, an integer, in the `checked()` function. The types need to match. Use `'1'` (in quotes) in the checked function.

Comment: Just try replacing - in 'prev-next' with underscore. We should not use - in name or id of any html control

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out. It was because on the template page where I output the form I had forgotten to include the `settings_fields` function, so it was not saving the setting. I added the following code below to that page and then it worked:

```
<?php settings_fields('prev-next-setting'); ?>
```